# Bottle @view vs template()

Tags: python, frameworks, template-engine, bottle

Rendering a view using [template()](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.template):

```
@get('/start/<page:int>')
def start(page=1):
    return template('start', page=page)
```

Same example using a [view()](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.view) decorator:

```
@get('/start/<page:int>')
@view('start')
def start(page=1):
    return dict(page=page)
```

Is there any difference between the two other than personal preference?

Comment: I would say: if you return a dict and the expected content type is json: do not render the template but return the json string. Can you verify whether this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I am not a professional developer so I may say something that goes against most basic good manners in coding, but I find more useful to use **return template()** because I can use several templates, while with view decorator that is not possible. E.G:

```
@get('/start/<page:int>')
def start(page=1):
    return template('header',username=username)+template('start', page=page)+template('foot')
```

Of course it is possible to do this with @views and  %include subtemplates in the template, and probably in one million other ways too, but... it's a difference!

...Or is it possible to call several templates within one @view?

Comment: Also if your template uses an open stream/reader that needs to be closed, you wouldn't use a decorator.  Example: `with query.reader() as results: return template('start', results=results)`

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is: no, there is no difference other than preference.  (The same way you could write a plugin or use a route decorator to accomplish many of the same tasks.)  They are equivalent ways of accomplishing the same goal: rendering a template.

The Bottle [template docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#templates) support this:

> To render a template you can use the template() function or the view() decorator.
>
> ...
>
> The view() decorator allows you to return a dictionary with the template variables instead of calling template().